# Aggregate sql raw records with benthos

Tags: mysql, benthos

I have this input in benthos to query lines of my db for a one-to-many relation between main table and child table :

```
input:
  sql_raw:
    driver: mysql
    dsn: user:password@tcp(ip:3306)/db
    query: |
      SELECT m.id, m.type, c.position, c.value
      FROM main m
      LEFT JOIN child c ON c.main_id = m.id
      ORDER BY m.id ASC, c.position ASC
```

With a simple output, i have this result :

```
{ "mid": 1, "type": "someType", "position": 0, "value": 2 }
{ "mid": 1, "type": "someType", "position": 1, "value": 5 }
{ "mid": 1, "type": "someType", "position": 2, "value": 20 }
{ "mid": 1, "type": "someType", "position": 3, "value": 8 }
```

I want an output like the following :

```
{
    "mid": 1,
    "type": "someType",
    "children": [
        {
            "position": 0,
            "value": 2,
        },
        {
            "position": 1,
            "value": 5,
        },
        {
            "position": 2,
            "value": 20,
        },
        {
            "position": 3,
            "value": 8,
        },
    ]
}
```

How should i do that ? With a cache ?
How to aggregate (join ?) messages ?

The only way i found so far is to create a pipeline with a sql_raw processor for each main id... not ideal as it requires as many sql requests as main table lines...

Comment: Does the data need to always exist in the mysql database because it seems like you are wanting to use JSON formatting instead of row,col like an excel file.  If that is the case, have you considered switching the MYSQL data over to a MongoDB so the data can already be in JSON format?

Comment: The mysql database is one of my sources, i need to export data from this database into a postgres db with many transformations (models are different). I guess that's exactly what benthos does :)

Comment: I see well good luck with the migration!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the entire dataset fit into memory? If yes, then you can use a `generate` input combined with a `sql_select` processor which returns a JSON array of messages that you can then massage into the desired structure via bloblang. Here's an example:

```yaml
input:
  generate:
    count: 1
    interval: 0s
    mapping: root = ""
  processors:
    - sql_select:
        driver: sqlite
        dsn: file:./foobar.db
        table: test
        columns:
          - mid
          - type
          - position
          - value
        init_statement: |
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
            mid int,
            type varchar,
            position int,
            value int
          );
          INSERT INTO test (mid, type, position, value) VALUES (1, 'someType', 0, 2), (2, 'someOtherType', 1, 5), (1, 'someType', 2, 20), (2, 'someOtherType', 3, 8);

    - unarchive:
        format: json_array
    - group_by_value:
        value: ${! json("mid") }-${! json("type") }
    - mapping: |
        root = if batch_index() == 0 { this.with("mid", "type").merge({"children": json().with("position", "value").from_all()}) } else { deleted() }

output:
  stdout: {}
```

I assume you have multiple values for `mid` and `type`, so I used `group_by_value` to split the single batch of rows into smaller batches based on these 2 fields and then I collapsed them into single messages with the structure you requested. Since I don't have your database, for this sample config I used a simple `sqlite` table that contains the results of your query.

If your dataset doesn't fit into memory, then there are workarounds, like fetching all the IDs, splitting them in small batches and then running the query you have for each of these batches. You might also want to use a cache to keep track of the processed IDs in case Benthos needs to be restarted. The config is a bit more involved though.